# html number input field always display spinner?

Tags: css, html

when I make a number input field like this:

```
<input type="number" />
```

Then the number field gets a spinner added to it whenever I hover over the field. A lot of people talk about how to disable these spinners like this:

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/turn-off-number-input-spinners/

But I would like to know how do you make them ALWAYS visible and not just when you hover over them?

Comment: In this case you're probably better of just using a third party input spinner, since they will behave consistently across different browsers and platforms.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It is not possible to do this with the Browser specific style. 
You would need to either build that functionality yourself using some Javascript or look for a premade script on the interwebs.

You can only hide those Shadow DOM elements as they trigger very browserspecific css-attributes to provide the functionalitys like onclick or onhover.

See: http://css-infos.net/property/-webkit-appearance (You could trigger another behaviour for your Input-Field, but you cant force it to be always visible)

Comment: This is incorrect, see @Hlynur Davíð Hlynsson's answer below

Answer (score 12):

It's the Chrome opacity settings that are giving you a headache. This will solve your issue:

```
input[type=number]:hover::-webkit-inner-spin-button, 
input[type=number]:hover::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
   opacity: 1;
}
```

This being the problem is kind of opaque.

Answer (score 1):

To make the spinner always show, leave out the ":hover" in Schneeez's answer.

```
input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
   opacity: 1;
}
```